# Obtener dirección IP del cliente en ASP.NET VB

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, iis

tras varios intentos de obtener el HOST y la IP de un cliente recurro a sus conocimientos.

Dentro de mi `login.aspx` tengo un fragmento en el load para obtener (o intentar) la dirección IP y el HOST, esto debido a que muchas de las acciones en la `intranet` que desarrollé tienen que ser desde 1 equipo en especifico. Este es el fragmento de código:

```
Dim strHostName as String = Dns.GetHostName()
Dim ipEntry as IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName)

lblIP.Text = System.net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).GetValue(0).ToString()
lblHost.Text = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.UserHostName).HostName
```

Y lo que obtengo al publicar en IIS es una IP que no corresponde (126.31.86.11 por ejemplo y la mia es la .20; En algunos equipos si funciona) y como hostname obtengo: "fileadm" .

Todo esto se realiza en una **intranet** con un servidor virtual con IIS, donde es publicada la web.

Agradezco su ayuda e intentaré estar atento al momento de sus preguntas.

Comment: Hace algún tiempo he tenido esos inconvenientes. Lo que me percaté, en mi entorno, es que había varias interfaces de Red, por lo que iterando por ellas está la "verdadera". El tema es discernir cuál es la verdadera desde la aplicación.

Comment: @NelsonRodriguezIgorra Gracias nelson, y de casualidad tienes alguna idea de como poder iterar en las redes o alguna documentación?, tengo mis ojos fritos tanto buscar respecto a por que no puedo encontrar la IP, todo funciona cuando compilo en server local pero no así en IIS, debe haber alguna configuración o algo que ignore por ese lado.

Comment: Quiza podrias intentar con Request.UserHostAddress().

Comment: @Shassain me aparece la ip de mi servidor de datos con Request.UserHostAddress(), quizas pueda haber algo con Javascript o no se, el codebehind es muy dificil de debuguear, ya que locar no hay problema, pero en la página publicada siempre cambia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finalmente logré dar con la ip correspondiente pero nunca tras el **CODEBEHIND**, sino que a través de Javascript. Este es el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script type="text/javascript">
const findLocalIp = (logInfo = true) => new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection 
                            || window.mozRTCPeerConnection 
                            || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

    if ( typeof window.RTCPeerConnection == 'undefined' )
        return reject('WebRTC not supported by browser');

    let pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
    let ips = [];

    pc.createDataChannel("");
    pc.createOffer()
     .then(offer => pc.setLocalDescription(offer))
     .catch(err => reject(err));
    pc.onicecandidate = event => {
        if ( !event || !event.candidate ) {
            // All ICE candidates have been sent.
            if ( ips.length == 0 )
                return reject('WebRTC disabled or restricted by browser');

            return resolve(ips);
        }

        let parts = event.candidate.candidate.split(' ');
        let [base,componentId,protocol,priority,ip,port,,type,...attr] = parts;
        let component = ['rtp', 'rtpc'];

        if ( ! ips.some(e => e == ip) )
            ips.push(ip);

        if ( ! logInfo )
            return;

        console.log(" candidate: " + base.split(':')[1]);
        console.log(" component: " + component[componentId - 1]);
        console.log("  protocol: " + protocol);
        console.log("  priority: " + priority);
        console.log("        ip: " + ip);
        console.log("      port: " + port);
        console.log("      type: " + type);

        if ( attr.length ) {
            console.log("attributes: ");
            for(let i = 0; i < attr.length; i += 2)
                console.log("> " + attr[i] + ": " + attr[i+1]);
        }

        console.log();
    };
} );
</script>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Local IP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My local IP is</h1>
    <p id="ip">Loading..</p>
    <script src="ip.js"></script>
    <script>
    let p = document.getElementById('ip');
    findLocalIp().then(
        ips => {
            let s = '';
            ips.forEach( ip => s += ip + '<br>' );
            p.innerHTML = s;
        },
        err => p.innerHTML = err
    );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

El código utiliza el famoso [event.candidate.candidate de RTCPeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent/candidate) en donde una de las propiedades que se recibe es la IP Privada. Funcionó en mi intranet.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Puedes [utilizar la colección](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp) `Request.ServerVariables`

Con `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")` obtienes la IP

Con `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST")` obtienes el nombre

De esta manera quedaría:

```
lblIP.Text = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
lblHost.Text = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST")
```

Si por medio hay un enrutador, probablemente enmascara la IP. Puedes probar con

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
```

Haciendo algo así:

```
Public Function GetIP() as string
    Dim context as System.Web.HttpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current
    Dim ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")

    if Not IsDBNull(ipAddress) AndAlso ipAddress <> "" then 
        Dim IPs() as string = ipAddress.Split(',')
        if IPs.Length > 0 then
            return IPs(0)
        End if
    End if

    return context.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
End Function
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Roger, de alguna manera esta fue una de las pruebas y en unos equipos me daba correcto, para otros me daba la IP incorrecta, si tienes alguna información extra del por que de esto te lo agradecería.

Comment: A los equipos que te da la ip incorrecta, que ip te debería dar y cuál es la que realmente te da? Estás seguro que los equipos no están detrás de un router haciendo NAT? Porque puede pasar que solo te de la ip del router.

Comment: @Sebastian La ip que me da es la del ejemplo, 126.31.86.11 y me debería dar 126.31.86.20, en programas locales lo hay problema obviamente al obtener la ip (en VB con un programa instalado por red)

Comment: @Sebastian cabe destacar además que es una intranet el lugar de trabajo

Comment: He editado la respuesta añadiendo una nueva posibilidad

Comment: @RogerTorné muchas gracias pero sigue dandome una ip incorrecta, me da la IP del HOST de mi BD,

Answer (score 1):

Iterar por las interfaces de Red de tu equipo:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

IPHostEntry host;
string localIP = "";
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{`introducir el código aquí`
    if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
    {
        localIP = ip.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Estimado, gracias por tu respuesta, pero tu código me devuelve la ip del servidor donde fue publicada la web, no la ip del cliente.

Answer (score 0):

No soy un experto, pero desde Javascript puro entiendo que no se puede.

Ya que es complicado debbuggear el code behind, podrías utilizar jquery y llamar a un servicio externo, podrías probar por ejemplo con [Cloudflare trace](https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace)

EDIT:

@harifo, intentaste mediante la [HttpRequest.UserHostAddress Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Agradecido por tu comentario amigo, pero es una intranet, por lo que no puedo llamar servicios externos

Comment: Por que con JS no se puede y con JQuery si?

Comment: @Aprendiz realmente no soy experto en la tecnología, pero estimo que se trata de una desición de diseño enfocado a la seguridad y las vulnerabilidades de Javascript.
Podés leer sobre esto en: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

Comment: No lo hallo sentido desde que JQuery está escrito en dicho lenguaje

Comment: @harifo edité mi respuesta, chequeaste con esta propiedad?

Comment: Si estimado, la chequee  y la utilicé en mis pruebas, pero es lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he encontrado un método para obtener la IP privada.
Puedes ver el script en mi pregunta de cómo puedo hacer la comparación para saber si la IP pública y privada son iguales o no.

[Comparar IP privada y publica con JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333059/comparar-ip-privada-y-publica-con-javascript)

Comment: De tu pregunta saqué mi respuesta, muchas gracias!