# Comparar IP privada y publica con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, ip

No se mucho de Javascript y necesito ayuda.
Quiero conseguir redirigir al usuario dependiendo de como se conecta, ya sea por red móvil o "fija".
La manera que he encontrado es comprobando si la IP privada es igual que la publica.
En caso de se iguales entiendo que esta conectado sin pasar por un Router , si son diferentes es que pasa por un Router o similar.

He encontrado como conseguir tanto la IP publica como la privada, pero no consigo hace la comparación.

Estos son los Scripts que tengo:

**IP publica**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function getIP(json) {
    document.write("My public IP address is: ", json.ip);
    }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://ipinfo.io/?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

**IP privada** [Esta es la pregunta de Stackoverflow donde lo he encontrado.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Local IP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My local IP is</h1>
    <p id="ip">Loading..</p>
    <script src="ip.js"></script>
    <script>
    let p = document.getElementById('ip');
    findLocalIp().then(
        ips => {
            let s = '';
            ips.forEach( ip => s += ip + '<br>' );
            p.innerHTML = s;
        },
        err => p.innerHTML = err
    );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Este es el contenido de ip.js**

```
/* ES6 */
const findLocalIp = (logInfo = true) => new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection 
                            || window.mozRTCPeerConnection 
                            || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

    if ( typeof window.RTCPeerConnection == 'undefined' )
        return reject('WebRTC not supported by browser');

    let pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
    let ips = [];

    pc.createDataChannel("");
    pc.createOffer()
     .then(offer => pc.setLocalDescription(offer))
     .catch(err => reject(err));
    pc.onicecandidate = event => {
        if ( !event || !event.candidate ) {
            // All ICE candidates have been sent.
            if ( ips.length == 0 )
                return reject('WebRTC disabled or restricted by browser');

            return resolve(ips);
        }

        let parts = event.candidate.candidate.split(' ');
        let [base,componentId,protocol,priority,ip,port,,type,...attr] = parts;
        let component = ['rtp', 'rtpc'];

        if ( ! ips.some(e => e == ip) )
            ips.push(ip);

        if ( ! logInfo )
            return;

        console.log(" candidate: " + base.split(':')[1]);
        console.log(" component: " + component[componentId - 1]);
        console.log("  protocol: " + protocol);
        console.log("  priority: " + priority);
        console.log("        ip: " + ip);
        console.log("      port: " + port);
        console.log("      type: " + type);

        if ( attr.length ) {
            console.log("attributes: ");
            for(let i = 0; i < attr.length; i += 2)
                console.log("> " + attr[i] + ": " + attr[i+1]);
        }

        console.log();
    };
} );
```

Comment: Y no sería mejor comprobar el UserAgent del navegador en lugar de mirar IPs? Por ejemplo, como se discute aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/7500028

Comment: Amigo, ocupé tu metodo para buscar ip locales y en mi caso funcionó excelente. Si lo publicas en [mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331883/obtener-direcci%c3%b3n-ip-del-cliente-en-asp-net-vb) te llevarás la recompensa

Comment: Entonces el problema solo es la comparación de las ip's?

Comment: @Julio los que quiero es que la conexión será por datos móviles no saber si el equipo es móvil, pc u otro.

Comment: Exacto @Emeeus.